# Using observer pattern when observers modify object state

Tags: design-patterns

I have a class `C` that has observers, `A` and `B` attached to it. The observer `B` modifies the state of the object that it receives and this must then be notified back to `A`. Till now I was simply invoking the class `C` notifyObservers() again from the observer `B` but this has a few problems:

- hard to understand
- `B` needs to ignore the second update because it raised the update

My initial idea was to make `B` notify its own observers where `A` is also registered as a observer with `B`.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I be using a different pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [Mediator pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator) is what you are looking for.

In this pattern you have a director which handles the communication between multiple (different) colleague objects. The colleagues know their director directly and they only communicate with it. The director manages the colleagues. So it decouples colleague objects and eases the communication protocol.

Maybe you could adapt it to your need.

Comment: Just so I understand your comment properly. You're saying that I should only notify observer `B` when the object is modified by anyone other than `B` itself and the logic to determine this would be in the mediator.

Comment: Yes that will probably work. You could add both *observer* notifications in the mediator. You could have a method `register_C_Observers` and a `register_ObjectChange_Observer`. Then there are methods `notify_C_Observers` and `notify_ChangeObject_Observers`. I'm not quite sure this mets the *exact* specification of the mediator pattern. But you decoupled communication into one class maybe leading to clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't introduce observers observing observers (B observing A). That doesn't sound like a fun time to write or debug.

I'd guess that what you have here is a cyclic dependency. The Observer pattern works really well when the observers need to reflect the current state of affairs in the observed, but they don't have a direct relationship. It sounds to me like in this particular case, A has a direct relationship with C in that A knows enough about C to change its state, but you're relying on the Observer pattern to propagate information from C to A that could go directly. The fact that you now have different "kinds" of events—the kind A generates and "other"—also suggests that the relationship between C and A isn't the observer/observed relationship you have between C and B. Is the relationship between C and A also one-to-one? That would be more evidence that you're simply applying the wrong pattern here. On the other hand, if one B can service multiple Cs, or vice versa, that's evidence that B and C are observer/observed.

I've seen this happen in my own code, when it looked like I had recursion due to my C changing at my A's behest then causing C to send another event that caused A to take the same action again. The solution I found at the time, which I don't like particularly, was to introduce different "categories" of observer and maintain separate observer lists and essentially different kinds of events for each category so that the category that could speak to the observed and cause new events would only cause events that got seen by the other category. In other words, a high-level observer and a low-level observer, and only the high-level observer could trigger low-level events. As I said, I don't like it. :)

To sum up, I recommend making the relationship between C and A explicit and leave C and B using Observer.

Comment: I simplified the case, there are many observers like `A`. Using categories would mean that I move all these observers to that category and keep `B` in a separate category. Is that what you're suggesting?